# what is the best method or tool to scrape web sites?

Tags: screen-scraping

i need to scrape (with approval) web sites before I start to write my own 
what is the best tool/way to scrape web sites, which is both fast (multithreaded) and easy to learn?

Comment: took the risk that "scrap" was supposed to be "scrape" :-)

Comment: if it is with approval, i'm sure he meant scrap ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this recent blog post by Lee Holmes](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/HTMLAgilityPackRocksYourScreenScrapingWorld.aspx). He wrote a pretty cool screen scraper using Powershell and the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: im more into linux c++/java world

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/). It has a display-less browser mode for fast scraping. The scripting language is very simple and quick to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

TagSoup, a SAX-compliant parser written in Java, parses HTML as it is found in the wild: poor, nasty and brutish, though quite often far from short.

Details here: http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this - https://scraperwiki.com/